# django 1.3 internationalization... switching language requires server restart?

Tags: django, internationalization

I used django 1.2 before and didn't have any problem switching language... In my template i have this...

```
<form action="/i18n/setlang/" method="post" class="forms">
{% csrf_token %}
<input name="next" type="hidden" value="/next/page/" />
<select name="language" id="select_langauge" class="m_show hide">
{% for lang in LANGUAGES %}
    {% if lang.0 != '' %}
        <option value="{{lang.0}}">{{lang.1}}</option>
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
</select>
```

This was working fine with django 1.2. But since upgraded to Django 1.3 this does not work. I can see that LANGUAGE_CODE changes, but the actual language output is not what I was expecting.

However, when i restart django server, it shows correct language. What am i missing???

I have this in my settings.py

```
LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'
SITE_ID = 1

USE_I18N = True

gettext = lambda s: s

LANGUAGES = (
    ('', gettext('Please select')),
    ('en', gettext('English')),
    ('ko', gettext('Korean')),
)

USE_L10N = True


MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.locale.LocaleMiddleware',
)
```

Comment: BTW, i'm using mongodb as database... Would this matter?

Comment: How does your view look like which process the language change? Can you give some information about your MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES setting? Thx

Comment: I must say its odd. I assume you are using django's internal `set_language` view according to your samples. Also the `LocaleMiddleware` should activate the language afterwards its changed in the session/cookie. What is strange though (just realized it) that your `LANGUAGE_CODE` setting does not match any language in `LANGUAGES` (it should be `en` or in `LANGUAGES` should be `en-us` instead). This `'Please select'` part is probably also not such a good idea (its not a language). Maybe you find a better way on the frontend side to achieve this behavior.

Comment: Try using ugettext_lazy instead of ugettext to get your translation string and see if it helps. If you i.e. do ugettext("string") outside a method - it might be evaluated only on the server reload (i.e. model field label). ugettext_lazy will evaluate the string, to put it simple, on display.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out.

To change language dynamically, using ugettext_lazy() fixed the problem. (Before I was using ugettext).

Reference: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/topics/i18n/internationalization/#lazy-translation